# Can't insert into MongoDB with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to insert data into a MongoDB database. I'm using the following minimum working example:

```
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.Connection()
db = conn.xxx
db.xxx.insert({'foo': 'bar'})
```

The database `xxx` is generated when I execute the code, but nothing is inserted. I can insert from the MongoDB command line but not through Python. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parenthesis. :)

Also, the second xxx that is not a database. Its a collection.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that was just a typo. Fixed the code in the question.

Comment: Code seems fine, try accessing using a dict like ie. db['collection'] see if it works.

Comment: I tried the dictionary-style access, but the results are the same. I think the problem is something with my Mongo installation? I previously had a script that worked to insert data into MongoDB, but now it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the output of: print conn